# Build Qt from source on Windows targeting Linux/ARM

Tags: windows, qt, arm, cross-compiling

I started out with [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/compile-qt-application-for-pi-from-windows) post on the Raspberry Pi exchange, which has led me down the path of building Qt from source.

After following [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420984/qtcreator-on-windows-to-cross-compile-for-linux-arm-with-codesourcery-toolchain) AND the example on [this blog post](http://c2143.blogspot.com/?view=classic), I can run `configure.exe` and generate the makefile with no errors (although that doesn't mean I did everything completely right), **but I get errors when I run make**.

**Here's my current setup:** MSVC2010 as the host compiler, and Sourcery CodeBench Lite as the cross compiler.  When I run `configure.exe`, I build for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++.  And of course, before I try to build anything, I run vcvarsall.bat from the command prompt I'm working in.

**Here's the problem:** After the makefile is generated, if I use jom to build, it will run for about 5 minutes, and then end with this error:

```
jom: C:\qt-pi\src\coreLib\Makefile [..\..\lib\libQtCore4.dll] Error 1
jom: C:\qt-pi\src\coreLib\Makefile [all] Error 2
jom: C:\qt-pi\Makefile [sub-sorelib-make_default-ordered] Error 2
jom: C:\qt-pi\Makefile [all] Error 2
```

Does anybody have any idea what I need to do to build Qt on Windows for Linux/ARM?  Thanks!

Comment: The guy on the blog has patched Qt.  Have you applied the patches? Also need to run *configure.exe* with some of the arguments he has given.  The 'libQtCore4.dll' means that someone still thinks they are in Windows land and the configure didn't go right.